# Does Google Analytics for Mobile provide any offline data tracking for Android apps?

Tags: android, mobile, google-analytics, analytics

Just as the questions says, does Google Analytics for Mobile provide any offline data tracking for Android apps?

Comment: Why has this question been voted down?

Comment: Why has this question been closed - its a very specific question, it is not ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad or rhetorical. And yet again no comment as to why.

Comment: Thanks for your question! However, this is not really the kind of question that Stack Overflow is here to answer. [Read this for more information](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) Once you have a specific question about a specific problem you are having with code you are writing, feel free to return.

Comment: I still dont really understand why this was closed - it is practical and answerable, it relates to a problem I'm currently facing and it is about a specific tool commonly used by programmers. Would the question have been left open if I'd have termed it like - "How do you get offline tracking working with google analytics for mobile"? I really don't think its ok to close a question without proper explanation. Also, the answer below does actually answer my question perfectly - it is in no way ambiguous, overly broad etc.#

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the application is offline, Google Analytics stores the events in a SQLite database and waits until the user is online again to send them.

Comment: [Queue_Time](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#qt)

Used to collect offline / latent hits. The value represents the time delta (in milliseconds) between when the hit being reported occurred and the time the hit was sent. The value must be greater than or equal to 0. Values greater than four hours may lead to hits not being processed.

Comment: What happened if user offline for a week or months?

Comment: So any event older than 4 hours ago will not be sent, right?