# Statistic from Google Analytics on Android devices for the period prior to an Internet connection

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

I added Google Analytics to my application and released the new version on 8 February. The app is currently installed on multiple devices with Android 4.4. Some of those devices connected to the Internet for the first time on April 1. I began to see the statistics from these devices, but only for April 1 and beyond. Why did I not also see the stats from 8 February to 31 March (before they had connected to the Internet)?

According to the documentation and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15829447/does-google-analytics-for-mobile-provide-any-offline-data-tracking-for-android-a), Google Analytics on Android devices without Internet access stores events in the database, and then sends the stored data once an Internet connection is established.

What do I need to do to display statistics for the period without the Internet connectivity? What do I need to do to see it in my reports?

I rebooted the devices and I am using the latest version of Google-Services and play-services-analytics (8.4.0).

Comment: Welcome to the site M. Nick. In the current format it's really unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Unfortunately it is unclear what you are asking with this question.

Comment: Edit question, please answer.